# How to set Redis to be case insensitive while filtering keys?

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I am using redis to set and filter key value pair in my application. But it return always case sensitive data while filtering using HSCAN. I need to get case insensitive data from redis. How can I get this?

How to set Redis to be case insensitive?

ex: If I search "foo", it should return the following results,

```
Foo
foo
FOO
fOO
```

Kindly provide your inputs on this.

Comment: did you try to use regex , somthing like `r.keys("*foo*")`

Comment: Yes, I am using HSCAN, 'HSCAN myhash 0 match *daily*' which is returning empty results. But when I use HSCAN development_partners 0 match *Daily*, it returns the following, 
127.0.0.1:6379> HSCAN myhash 0 match *Daily*
   1) "The Daily News"
   2) "dailynews"
   3) "Daily News Update"
   4) "news updated"

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to do that, however, you can hack it.

Instead of doing: `HSET hash foo val`, `HSET hash Foo val`, and `HSET hash fOo val`, you make these fields has a common prefix, e.g. **FOO:**

```
HSET hash FOO:foo val
HSET hash FOO:Foo val
HSET hash FOO:fOo val
```

Then instead of call `HSCAN hash 0 MATCH foo*`, you can use `HSCAN hash 0 MATCH FOO:*` to scan items case-insensitively.

In a word, encode your field with a case-insensitive prefix, e.g. all chars uppercased or lowercased.